# A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'WScript.CreateObject'

Tags: vbscript

Trying to execute:

```
Set objWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

Getting error:

```
[![PS C:\Windows\system32> Set objWshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set-Variable : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 
'WScript.CreateObject'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set objWshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) \[Set-Variable\], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetVaria 
   bleCommand][1]][1]
```

This however works:

```
$WSH = New-Object -Com WScript.Shell
$WSH.Run("explorer.exe""")
```

I am trying to [run this](https://superuser.com/questions/682211/cisco-anyconnect-v3-1-autologin/885506) which requires the shell and context of it :

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run """%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpnui.exe"""

WScript.Sleep 3000

WshShell.AppActivate "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client"

WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

WScript.Sleep 5000

WshShell.SendKeys "PASSWORD"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Comment: Double check the [RADA's answer](https://superuser.com/a/885506/376602) linked already in your question: _Save this script as FILENAME._**vbs**. This is VBScript, not PowerShell!

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you're just running into trouble translating the VBS code into powershell.  There are some subtle syntactic differences such as:

```
$WSH = New-Object -Com wscript.shell

$WSH.run("executable")
$WSH.AppActivate("name")
$WSH.SendKeys("key to send")
```

You'll use powershell's sleep though:

```
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
```